# Is using DeepL translation good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo

I saw using Google translation is clearly bad because you're doing automatic translation without decent human revision also Google can confirm that you are using Google translation. But how about DeepL translation, that enables you high quality translation for some languages, different from Google translation or Bing translation? Can Google robot recognize content that created from DeepL, or very high quality machine translation?

Answer (score 3):

I only did a single test to compare it with Google. I think Google won this round, but both did a very similar job. The sentences are long and unnatural. The meaning of important points is lost completely with repeated mistakes for quoted words. I would only read this translation if I was desperate and it was the only source of information available (not likely).

So, humans will notice it and that's bad for your SEO. And if you can't fool Google with its own translator, it's probably not fooled by DeepL either. It's basically the same output. Of course this is only one test and it's possible DeepL is better at other languages or styles.

Tested the first paragraph of the [Italian Wikipedia article on translation](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traduzione).

- **Google Italian to English:**

> Translation is an activity that includes the interpretation of the
> meaning of a text ("source", "origin", "starting" or "prototext") and
> the subsequent production of a new text, equivalent to the original
> one, but in another language ("target", "target" or "metatext"
> language). However, the term "translation" does not only indicate the
> act of translating, but also the translated text resulting from this
> activity; for these reasons, often some scholars and theorists have
> preferred to avoid ambiguity by using a different and more specific
> term: for example, the noun "translating" (Henri Meschonnic) or the
> phrases "translating activity" (activité traduisante), "operation
> translating "(opération traduisante) (Georges Mounin) or others.

- **DeepL Italian to English:**

> Translation is an activity that involves the interpretation of the
> meaning of a text ("source", "source", "source" or "prototext") and
> the subsequent production of a new text, equivalent to the source
> text, but in another language ("target", "target" or "metatext"
> language). However, the term "translation" does not only indicate the
> act of translating, but also the translated text resulting from this
> activity; for these reasons, some scholars and theorists have often
> preferred to avoid ambiguity by using a different and more specific
> term: for example, the noun "translating" (Henri Meschonnic) or the
> locutions "translating activity" (activité traduisante), "translating
> operation" (opération traduisante) (Georges Mounin) or others.

Comment: um, they are looks similar indeed. As I speak Japanese, I think DeepL is doing really great job compared to Google translation for the language. So you think if the result of the two were obviously different, maybe Google cannot recognize it as a machine translation one?

Comment: @pupsozeyde - It's possible. Google may not detect that it's a machine translation, but it can detect what happens when humans try to read it. If many people close the page too soon (because of a low quality translation) then your website / page will lose rank. It's also possible that Google will reverse engineer all popular translation software and find a way to identify the output.